# How to distribute a file to multiple clients efficiently?

Tags: architecture, distributed, p2p, distributed-computing, bittorrent

I am building an application which, hopefully, will be installed on many clients (desktop and mobile). Client A may generate a file and publish that he has it. Clients B-Z may decide they want this file.

Some assumptions:

- files are ~2MB.
- When one client generates a file chances are most other clients will want that file. I guess this is not the case with most P2P apps.
- I cannot afford an expensive server farm.

I am thinking to use the bittorrent protocol.

Is it a good approach assuming I use a public tracker or DHT?

Comment: How many is "many"?  Are we talking hundreds, hundreds of thousands, millions?  Are there spikes in demand or is it fairly even?

Comment: Millions (if my program will be any good :) Demand is even.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which programming language you are using.

If you are using a .net language you could use MS Sync Framework (which is free) See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/sync/bb980926.aspx

Comment: I need to support multiple platforms (devices) but this is still interesting